# web to case not working

Tags: web2case

I am trying to implement the web to lead functionality. But for whatever reasons, the leads are not getting inserted into salesforce.
Any thoughts??

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Check your email. SF will send you an exception email of what is wrong here

Comment: Thanks Tushar., but didnt recieve any mail. And i Creating it in sandbox

Comment: web to case or web to lead? - title and body are in disagreement

Answer (score 0):

In order for Cases to be created through a web-to-case form in Sandbox, you must first modify the HTML code generated through:

```
Setup | App Setup | Customize | Self-Service | Web-to-Case.
```

As generated by setup from within Sandbox, the form POST line reads:

```
<form action="http://test.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
```

You must substitute "test" in the above line with your sandbox instance name (cs1, cs2, cs3 etc).

For example, if your sandbox instance is CS1, you must change this code to read:

```
<form action="https://cs1.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
```

If this does not resolve the issue, check if there are multiple case record types in the org, and make sure you add the following to the code:

```
<input type=hidden name="recordType" id="recordType" value="012xxxxxxxxxx">
```

Comment: <form action="https://aci--uat.cs40.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">., but doesnt work dont know

Comment: @parthipan did you add `https://` because I can't find it in your comment?

Comment: <form action="https://aci.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

Comment: @parthipan I still don't see this.

Comment: <form action="https: //aci--UAT.cs40.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

Comment: sry abt that i paste., it didnt show up

Comment: @parthipan try to use this `https: //cs40.salesforce.com`

Comment: No, Its doesnt go to the return URL itself. I did trying everything but unable to find the extact solution

Comment: @parthipan can your share your html code. You can hide orgId and other sensitive data.

Comment: Sry for the late response @tushar

Comment: <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">                                                                                                            <form action="https://aci--UAT.cs40.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

<input type=hidden name="orgid" value="">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="">
<label for="name">Contact Name</label><input  id="name" maxlength="80" name="name" size="20" type="text" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

Comment: @parthipan I think you are missing required fields. From which email address you are sending email check that you should recieve an email also in your `Emailtolead` to setting enable your email address as well.

Comment: <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> <form action="aci--UAT.cs40.my.salesforce.com/servlet/…; method="POST"> <input type=hidden name="orgid" value=""> <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="mymailid@gmail.com"> <label for="name">Contact Name</label><input id="name" maxlength="80" name="name" size="20" type="text" /><br> <input type="submit" name="submit"> </form>

Comment: web to lead worked fine., but web case is oly giving me a pblm

Comment: @parthipan check `webtocase` setting also the required field as well.

Comment: Okay Tushar., I recheck it..

Comment: Its finally working but not fully., Mail notification to customer is disabled. Any ideas???

Comment: there is setting . You need to check that.

Comment: oh Thanks but where will find that setting ???